# Get the latest data from database

Tags: php, laravel

I need to fetch the latest data from the table. I have date passed in URL and I filter using it. So, I have something like this:

```
$latest = Latest::select('s_customer', 's_product', 's_starttermin')
        ->leftJoin('temp_cat', 'temp_cat.spotid', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
        ->where('s_active', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy('s_starttermin', 'desc')
        ->limit(50);

if (!empty(Input::get('date'))) {
    $latest = $latest->where('s_starttermin', '=', Input::get('date'));
}
```

And for example, today I do not have any latest products for `2017-09-28`. `$latest` is an empty array in that case. The last one was three days ago. How can I fetch only latest data? Reminder: I filter using `s_starttermin`...

Answer (score 2):

I created a function to recall it till we found our latest records but be careful, if you don't have any record it will loop till infinite, I would add some `$opportunities` variable or something:

```
    public function getLatest($date){
        $latest = Latest::select('s_customer', 's_product', 's_starttermin')
                    ->leftJoin('temp_cat', 'temp_cat.spotid', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
                    ->where('s_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('s_starttermin', 'desc')->limit(50);

        if (!empty($date)) {
            $latest = $latest->where('s_starttermin', '=', Input::get('date'));
        }

       $latest = $latest->get();

       if(empty($latest)){
          return $this->getLatest(Carbon::parse($date)->subDay());
       }else{
         return $latest;
       }
     }
```

pass him your `Input::get('date')`

```
$this->getLatest(Input::get('date'))
```

Comment: But I have to get the results for specified date. That's why I have filter date in my form which is passed as `Input::get('date')` .. If there are no results for today, I need to display latest results from yesterday (for example)

Comment: you misunderstood me. This will show the all results less than today's date. I want to show only for specified date. If there are no results for `2017-09-28` and the last one are from `2017-09-27`, then I want to show all results from `2017-09-27`

Answer (score 0):

In your logic everything breaks with your `if` condition. I suggest you query your dataset without the condition first and from the result set filer out appropriate record according to your logic.

```
$all = Latest::select('s_customer', 's_product', 's_starttermin')
    ->leftJoin('temp_cat', 'temp_cat.spotid', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
    ->where('s_active', '=', 1)
    ->orderBy('s_starttermin', 'desc')
    ->limit(50)
    ->get(); 

$latest = $all->first(); // because you use `desc` you get the latest here.

if (!empty($date = Input::get('date'))) {
     // if the `$date` is preset and it's equal to `$data->s_starttermin`, you'll get it as the latest one.
     $latest = $all->filter(function($data) use ($date) {
          return $data->s_starttermin == $date;
     });
}
```

Give this a go and please sorry if formatting is wrong as I on my phone :)

Comment: I get this error.. `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()`

Comment: Oops, I adjusted the code. I missed `get()` part. Please check now.

Comment: But still I get the error: `Method limit does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you..

```
$latest = Latest::select('s_customer', 's_product', 's_starttermin')
            ->leftJoin('temp_cat', 'temp_cat.spotid', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
            ->where('s_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('s_starttermin', 'desc')->take(50)->get();

if (!empty(Input::get('date'))) {
    $latest = $latest->where('s_starttermin', '=', Input::get('date'))->orderBy('s_starttermin','desc')->get();
}
```